# D&D My character is not interested in flirty NPC

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, social, romance

I’m playing a Drunken Master Wood Elf Monk named Jade. Last session, my party after about a weeks worth of traveling had finally made it to their destination. Our party rested up and then decided to stock up on supplies before meeting our contact. My character (who is a sage and loves books) decides to go to the local bookshop and purchase some books along with some parchment. As Jade was leaving, the NPC who was running the bookshop scribbles a note on one of her pieces of paper. She doesn’t read it until late into night. After reading it she finds out that the bookshop NPC (I don’t remember his name, I had forgot to ask) wanted to meet her at one of taverns in town. Jade meets up with him and he starts flirting with her.

My character Jade is extremely awkward in social situations and is completely oblivious  to people hitting on her. She blushes and then luckily the contact (a monk whom her party was planning to meet with) takes her aside to speak with her.

The NPC is clearly super into my character but my character isn’t. How should I go about role playing this out and being able to kindly reject him?

Comment: Hi Emily, welcome to the site!  Your question has been flagged as possibly being too opinion-based to answer.  You might wish to review [this page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) about asking questions in the manner best suited to the site, and then edit your post to elicit more objective answers.  You might wish to clarify _why_ you want to reject this NPC kindly, or what problems you see arising with not doing so.  The more clear you can be about what your problem is, the more likely someone can give you a helpful and objective, or at least subjective but experienced, answer.

Comment: Just so we're clear, are you just asking about how to navigate this interaction while staying true to your in-character motives, or is the flirtation troublesome to you as a player?

Comment: How does Jade feel about the situation and how does that differ/allign with what you want to do?

Comment: Hi @Emily/@TheRise, it looks like you've accidentally made two accounts. You should go through the process of getting them [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you own your own question (with all the benefits thereof).

Answer (score 4):

## Talk To Your DM

It's a little bit strange that your DM is initiating a romance subplot.

A romance subplot means that the DM spends a lot of time having a one-on-one conversation with one player.  During this time, all the other players at the table pretty much sit there doing nothing because their character isn't present in the scene.  Many DMs don't like doing that to their players, so we try to avoid romance subplots.

It seems like the fastest way out of this problem is to drop your DM a quick note saying: "hey, it's nice of you to arrange this personal story for my character, but I want to let you know that I'm not really interested in doing a romance subplot."  If I got a note like that, I would immediately drop the subplot and never bring it up again.

## Also, About Your Character

You've written:

> My character Jade is extremely awkward in social situations and is completely oblivious to people hitting on her.

and I'm contractually obliged to point out that this is My Guy Syndrome.  We have a [very popular article](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it) on this topic, and it's worth reading the top answer.

The short version is: you've decided that your character is awkward in social situations and doesn't like flirting.  If that's a match for how you, the player, feel, then that's fine!  But if you felt like maybe it might be fun to have your character be flirty and social, you can just decide that your character wants to try being flirty and social now.  Roleplaying should be fun; if you discover that your roleplaying is causing you to not have fun, you should choose to roleplay differently.

Comment: We don't actually know that the GM is attempting to initiate a romance subplot. The one time that an NPC came on most strongly to a PC I was playing, it was a one-off attempt to get my character into a situation which would allow him to be framed for a crime, not to establish an ongoing plot thread specific to my character. There's nothing in the question to indicate that this isn't a similar situation.

Comment: Whether "this is My Guy Syndrome" depends on whether it's interfering with the other players' ability to enjoy the game. Playing your character according to your understanding of their motives and personality is not, in itself, a problem; it's normal roleplaying.

Comment: "My Guy Syndrome" is typically characterized by a player having a character do things that are detrimental to the other players fun because "that's what my guy would do". I don't see how this is even close.

Comment: I think "My Guy Syndrome" also applies to players having a character do things that are detrimental to their *own* fun.